# SecurityError error in html2canvas on localhost is cors issue?

Tags: spring-boot, cors, screenshot, html2canvas

```
function screenShot() {
    html2canvas(document.body, { allowTaint: true, useCORS: true }).then(function (canvas) {
        fetchFile(canvas.toDataURL())
    });
}
```

There is an html code like the one above, if you run it after connecting to Android, it runs without problems.

The problem occurs on iPhone (ios). The following error occurs in the chrome browser, and the canvas url cannot be retrieved.

```
[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: SecurityError: The operation is insecure.

    toDataURL (show:405)
    (익명 함수) (show:405)
```

The environment is springBoot and runs on localhost:8080, and the browser also accesses localhost:8080, is it a cors problem? Or do I need some other settings?

I'm using the above code to take a full screenshot of a webpage and download it, if I can't solve this problem in ios, is there a way to programmatically move it to the device screenshot page?

Please advise, thank you.